# How to check if function is active on statusbar?

Tags: vim, count, character, statusbar

I added this function in _vimrc to **count characters while typing**:

```
   function! Count2Cursor()
      let mycount2cursor = strlen(substitute(join(add(getline(1,line('.')-1),strpart(getline('.'),0,col('.')-1)),'.'),'.','.','g'))+1
      return mycount2cursor
    endfunction
```

This is the code **to activate** it on the statusbar:

```
:set statusline+=%1*\ Chars2Cursor:\%{Count2Cursor()}
```

This is the code **to disable** it on the statusbar:

```
:set statusline-=%1*\ Chars2Cursor:\%{Count2Cursor()}
```

What I want to do is to integrate both lines (activate/disable) in one line: `Toggle Chars2Cursor`.
How can I check if the code is activated/disabled on the statusbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current value of `'statusline'` option via `&statusline`. Pattern matching will then tell you whether it already contains your function.

```
:command! ToggleChars2Cursor
\   if &statusline =~# 'Chars2Cursor' |
\       set statusline-=%1*\ Chars2Cursor:\%{Count2Cursor()} |
\   else |
\       set statusline+=%1*\ Chars2Cursor:\%{Count2Cursor()} |
\   endif
```